# Should と be appended in 「自分の利益を得んがための発言では、人の心を動かせない。」?

Tags: jlpt

In my JLPT prep book, I have the following sentence (no official translation available),

> 自分の利益を得んがための発言では、人の心を動かせない。

I am wondering if there is not a missing と at the end. Indeed, here, it would translate as “In this speech made so that I get some profit I will not move the heart of people” but with と it would become “In this speech that should get me some profit I should move the heart of people”.

My translation is not really good but I hope it is understandable.

Can you confirm that と is missing? or do I understant the sentence the wrong way?

Maybe I misunderstood the sentence and it just means “I won't move people with a speech made for my own profit/in order that I get profit”

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「[自分]{じぶん}の[利益]{りえき}を[得]{え}んがための[発言]{はつげん}では、[人]{ひと}の[心]{こころ}を[動]{うご}かせない。」

If this is a stand-alone sentence without any context, it is already a ***perfect*** sentence.  There is no need to add a 「と」 at the end.

In that case, the sentence would mean:

> "If it were a statement made to profit oneself, it could not move anyone's heart." or
>
> "A statemnet that is made to profit oneself would not move anyone's heart."

Regardless of the possible variety of translations, the fact remains that the original sentence would be 100% correct, grammatical, natural, etc.

***If***, however, there were a context in which 「自分の利益を得んがための発言では、人の心を動かせない。」 is what someone ***said, thought, heard, was taught, etc.***, then a 「と」 can be added at the end.  Needless to say, that 「と」 would be quotative.

For example, it is completely grammatical and natural to say:

> 「[父]{ちち}は[言]{い}っていた。自分の利益を得んがための発言では、人の心を動かせない**と**。」
>
> 「[何]{なに}かの[本]{ほん}で[読]{よ}んだことがある。自分の利益を得んがための発言では、人の心を動かせない**と**。」

Comment: I was completely mistaken, thank you for shedding light.